# Is this how you would define multiple constants using index?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, constants

So just a quick questions since I'm relatively new to javascript.

Let's say I have

```js
const {a, b, c, d} = items[i]
```

and I have a list of items somewhere in the document. What would this code render? What does it essentially stand for? I know how to define multiple constants in one line but I get confused when you incorporate the index (i). Any explanation would help. Thank a ton!

Answer (score 0):

`{a, b, c, d}` means you are destructuring the properties of an object. In this case you are destructuring to define the `const` variables `a,b,c,d`.

`items` is built with multiple objects. So we destructure the `items[2]` object properties to define the `const` variables.

```js
const items = [
{a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d:0},
{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d:1},
{a: 2, b: 2, c: 2, d:2}
] 

const {a, b, c, d} = items[2]

console.log(a) // <--- outputs 2
```

You can also destructure the array by doing something like so:

```js
const items = [
{a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d:0},
{a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, d:1},
{a: 2, b: 2, c: 2, d:2}
] 

const [obj1, obj2, obj3] = items

console.log(obj1) // <--- outputs {a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d:0}
```